# How to get value after serverside call javascript lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, actionfunction, array

I do a serverside call to get my accounts which returns my accounts. I want to be able to use the returned accounts as a variable to work with. How do I accomplish this. My returnvalue gives me an array, when I try to get this array and pass it to a variable it returns empty.

Javascript

```
 getAccountList: function(component,event,helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');
    // Set up the callback
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
     component.set("v.accounts", actionResult.getReturnValue());  alert(actionResult.getReturnValue());
    });

      $A.enqueueAction(action);

     var acc = component.get("v.accounts"); 
     alert(acc);
  },
```

Comment: Is your "accounts" attribute is of type Account[]? Also, can you check the state of the actionResult in your callback method?

Comment: `$A.enqueueAction(action)` adds the server-side action as queue of actions to be executed asynchronous and have callbacks.you put an alert  after `$A.enqueueAction(action)` it is called first thats y you getting empty.you check it in successcallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `$A.enqueueAction(action);` makes an asynchronous network request and result is processed via a callback. In your code, you are not waiting for callback to complete before trying to access the result.

Here are steps you can follow to get the list of accounts in your lightning component.

Write an Apex controller and add an `@AuraEnabled` method which returns list accounts.

```
// snippet
public class MyAccountListController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return [Select Id, Name From Account limit 100];
    }
}
```

Create a Lightning component and bind the Apex controller to component.

```
// snippet
<aura:component controller="MyAccountListController">

</aura:component>
```

In your component, declare an attribute to hold Account records as follows.

```
<!-- list of accounts -->
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]" />
```

Add a javascript function in Client-side controller for lightning component to get the list of accounts and assign it to attribute in lightning component.

```
getAccountList: function(component,event,helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');
    // Set up the callback
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        var state = actionResult.getState();
        if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.accounts", actionResult.getReturnValue());
            console.log(component.get("v.accounts"));
        } else if(state == 'ERROR') {
            console.error(actionResult.getError());
        } else {
            console.log("something went wrong!");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Call the `getAccountList` javascript function from lightning component. It's upto you how want to invoke that function. Just for completion, I'm going bind to this function to `init` event of lightning component. It will load account list when component loads.

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getAccountList}" value="{!this}" />
```

Hope this helps.